# Database management Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to set in my application multiple connection to multiple database, one for development, one for tests and other for production. I have found on stack overflow some tips, to get by url and pass many and different settings, so I've improved it on my app, but I realized that when I try to run migrations that don't work because that has no url to pass, Is there another way to do that? Or do you intend to manage app mode different from what is it today? This could also define debug as false if production or test and true if development.

Comment: Do you need to switch between databases from the same weblocation? Because I normally develop on my own machine, set up a test version on my own server and finally have production at the customer's server. Which are three different locations.

Comment: Yes, this is my case, but I'd like to set a variable or a method that I would not need to set a different configuration for every place where my app will run, so I will need less configurations or conflicts between my branches.

Comment: Have you considered using environment variables (coming from your servers' host configs) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like, in my path.php I defined APP_MODE variable as 'development' then in my app.php I create a case option if development this database, and app will have this behaviour if 'tests' this variables database and this another beahviour, if 'production' then another one. This help me to create many branches one for each APP_MODE, then when I need to send to tests or production I just make a merge and then send to jenkins deploy it

Answer (score 1):

Check what the hostname of your development computer is.

On linux or Windows:

```
hostname
```

Make a copy of your `app/config/app.default.php` to a file with that hostname instead of the word `default`.

Edit the `app/Console/Installer.php` file can change the `createAppConfig` function as follows:

```
public static function createAppConfig($dir, $io)
{
    $appConfig = $dir . '/config/app.php';
    $defaultConfigPath = $dir . '/config/app.default.php';
    $hostnameConfigPath = $dir . '/config/app.' . gethostname() . '.php';
    $defaultConfig = file_exists($hostnameConfigPath) ? $hostnameConfigPath : $defaultConfigPath;
    if (!file_exists($appConfig)) {
        copy($defaultConfig, $appConfig);
        $io->write('Created `config/app.php` file');
    }
}
```

Now when you run `composer install` on your project it will use either the `app.default.php` configuration, or another configuration that matches the hostname of the current machine.

This couples all the configuration settings to an environment or a default. That might solve some of your issues, but if you want to switch databases on your development workstation. It's just easier to manually edit the `app.php` file yourself. If you have to do anything more complicated than that.

Comment: Not bad. I use a separate configuration file that I place one level above the webroot and include() from index.php. Placing it outside of the webroot means a) it cannot be accessed remotely and b) it's usually outside of your source control.